# Can VGA port display SVGA, HDTV, WHUXGA?

Tags: vga, cable

I am confused with VGA port, and the cables. Since the VGA resolution is "640 x 480" and there's a VGA, SVGA cables in market. Would I need a QXGA or WHUXGA ports to be able to display those resolutions to an external monitor? Or, are there only just cables called QXGA or WHUXGA that work with VGA port?

Comment: D-sub certainly supports at least 1080p at 60Hz, but you wouldn't want to use an analog cable for high resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same VGA port and the same VGA cable may be used for both VGA and its extensions such as SVGA, QXGA and others. The supported resolutions depend on the graphics card and the monitor. However, because VGA is an analog interface, the image quality may vary, and some cables may work better than others. Digital interfaces such as DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort offer generally better performance at high resolutions.

Further reading: [Wikipedia: VGA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector)

Comment: Does this mean there are QXGA and WHUXGA cables which plug into VGA? or just one cable and one port for everything?

Comment: The same cables work for everything, but the quality may vary. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @user12184 There's no such thing as a QXGA/WHUXGA cable, they're just names given to specific resolutions. Different cables support different resolutions. HDMI 2.0, for example, supports 4K at 60Hz. Also note that VGA is analog while most of the newer standards, like HDMI and DisplayPort, are digital.

Comment: So, how come there's an SVGA cable if VGA cable should be enough?

Comment: @user12184 That's probably just marketing. Or do you see any difference? There should be 15(+15) pins in the same arrangement and same connections in both cables.

Comment: The construction of the VGA cable can be factor with higher resolutions.  For high resolutions and/or longer lengths, quality 75 Ohm coaxial cable with BNC connector is preferred for each of the five signals (RGBHV).  A [VGA breakout cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=vga+breakout+cable&client=ubuntu&hs=B6x&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK6IaGzK_KAhVN5WMKHTF7CpYQsAQISA&biw=1280&bih=654) is often used.